# ModelBuilder - use in line variable in expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, query

I have an in line variable of two fields (field1_field2) in modelbuilder.  Using the make feature layer tool, I would like to make an expression that queries field2.  Can an expression in the make feature layer be used to parse and query the in line variable.  I've tried the query below and some variations of it but not having any luck.

EVENTKEY = %Value%.split("_")[-1]

EVENTKEY is the field I'm querying and %Value% is the in line variable consisting of field1_field2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got this figured out by using the %output_value% of the calculate value tool as the input to the make feature layer tool.